# State on *-algebra: $\phi(|f+g|^2)$ when $\phi(|f|^2),\phi(|g|^2)>0$ for monomials

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, dual-spaces

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the unital *-algebra generated by $N^2$ projections $u_{i,j}=u_{i,j}^2=u_{i,j}^*$, such that the rows/columns are partitions of unity $\sum_k u_{ik}=1_\mathcal{A}=\sum_k u_{kj}$, and $u_{ik}u_{i\ell}=u_{kj}u_{\ell j}=\delta_{k,\ell}$. That is $\mathcal{A}$ is the *algebra of regular functions on the quantum permutation group $S_N^+$. It has, for $N>4$, various completions to a $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra*.

**If you want, please just assume that $\mathcal{A}$ is generated by $N^2$ projections. I suspect that the relations beyond that don't make things harder or easier.**

We will use the notation $|x|^2=x^*x$. Suppose that there exists a state $\phi:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, a positive functional such that $\phi(1_{\mathcal{A}})=1$, such that for all **monomials** $f\in\mathcal{A}$, that $\phi(|f|^2)>0$.

> 1. If $g\in\mathcal{A}$ is another monomial, can we say anything useful
>    about:
>
> $$\phi(|f+g|^2)?$$
>
> 2. Can we say that $\phi(|f+g|^2)\geq 0$ with equality only when $f=-g$?
> 3. Is $f=-g$ possible for monomial $f,\,g\in\mathcal{A}$?
> 4. Can we conclude that $\phi$ is faithful, that for all $a\in\mathcal{A}$, $\phi(|a|^2)=0\Rightarrow a=0$

Comment: Not entirely sure what a *monomial* is in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JP, you are going to laugh at this, but the counter examples are always the same!

As you mentioned that the relations are not so important, I will ignore them.  In this  case I presume that the number
$N^2$ is not so crucial either, so I will look instead at just two projections.

In the algebra  $C([0,1],M_2)$, consider the two projections $P$ and $Q$, defined by
$$
  P(t)= \pmatrix{1 & 0 \cr 0 & 0}, \quad \text{and} \quad
  Q(t):= \pmatrix{t & \sqrt{t-t^2}\cr \sqrt{t-t^2} & 1-t},
  $$
for all $t\in  [0,1]$.

By the universal property of $\mathcal A$, there is a *-homomorphism
$$
  \pi :  \mathcal A \to C([0,1],M_2),
  $$
sending  the two projections $p$ and $q$ generating $\mathcal A$, respectively to $P$ and  $Q$.

Fixing any $t_0$ in $(0, 1)$,  consider the state $\phi$ on $\mathcal A$ defined by
$$
  \phi(a) = \langle \pi (a)|_{t_0}e_1, e_1\rangle .
  $$
In other words, $\phi(a)$ is the top-left entry of the matrix $\pi (a)|_{t_0}$.

We claim that $\phi$ is strictly positive on any monomial,  that is,  on any product whose terms lie in the set $\{p, q\}$.  The reason is that the matrices
$$
  \pmatrix{1 & 0 \cr 0 & 0}, \quad \text{and} \quad
  \pmatrix{{t_0} & \sqrt{{t_0}-{t_0}^2}\cr \sqrt{{t_0}-{t_0}^2} & 1-{t_0}},
  $$
have the following two properties

- all entries are nonnegative,
- the top-left entry is strictly positive,

and   it is easy to see that the set of matrices satisfying these properties is closed under multiplication.

Thus,  if $f$ is a monomial, then $|f|^2$ is also a monomial, whence
$\phi( |f|^2)>0$.

However, $\phi$ is not faithful.  To see this,  consider the element
$$
  a = pqp-t_0p.
  $$
We then have that $\pi (a)|_{t_0}=0$, so also $\phi(a^*a) = 0$.

On the other hand,  one may verify by direct computation that
$$
  \pi (a)|_{t}\neq 0,\quad\forall  t\in  (0, 1)\setminus \{t_0\},
  $$
so $a\neq 0$.

Comment:  I will have to have a think about this tomorrow in terms of how this relates to what I am working on. Thanks as ever.